# Child table is not updating rather the parent table version number is getting updated in Spring, Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm doing a crud operation on parent and child table where parent and child have OneToOne bi-directional mapping and child table has two embedded class which is Address-Details and Audit-Details and in Address-Details has an Embedded class called Address where its has basic address attributes.

I'm using Spring MVC with JSP and Hibernate 5 Java Configuration.

My questions

1. am i following the right code practice.
2. is there an issue on the Hibernating mapping do i need to use the join table.
3. if you people have the time [the full code](https://github.com/vikramvikki33/Spring-MVC-Java-Config.git) available in git please suggest me a good practice on writing the code.
4. because when i did a junit test on this it save by managing the both side but in MVC its not working.

Here are my Classes the Domain objects the Client Class the Parent Class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLN_HDR_TB")
public class Clients implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="SYSID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="VERSION")
    @Version
    private int version;

    @NotBlank(message = "Client Name can't be Blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50, message = "Client Name should be greater then 3 Characters Or Less Then 50 Characters")
    @Column(name = "CLIENT_NAME", length = 50, unique = true)
    private String clientName;

    **@ElementCollection
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clients", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<SubClients> subClientsSet;**


    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST,  mappedBy="clients")
    private ClientsDetails clientDetails;

    @Embedded
    private AuditDetails auditDetails;
```

the setters and getter are removed as they are generated using eclipse code snippet and equals and hashcode too.

The Child class Client Details which has the Join Column.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CLN_DTL_TB")
public class ClientsDetails implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="SYSID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="VERSION")
    @Version
    private int version;

    @Column(name="CLN_DESC", length=50)
    private String clientDescription;

    @Embedded
    private AddressDetails addressDetails;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="C_ID", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="CC_ID_SK"))
    private Clients clients;

    @Embedded
    private AuditDetails auditDetails;
```

the setters and getter are removed as they are generated using eclipse code snippet and equals and hashcode too.

The Address details Class which is an embedded object referenced in the client details class.

```
@Embeddable
public class AddressDetails implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "CONTACT_PERSON_NAME", length = 50)
    private String contactPersonName;

    @Column(name = "CONTACT_REFERENCE", length = 50)
    private String contactReference;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;
```

the setters and getter are removed as they are generated using eclipse code snippet.

The Adress class which is referenced in the address details and contains the basic address attributes.

```
@Embeddable
public class Address implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */`enter code here`
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="ADDRESS_LINE1" , nullable=true)
    private String addressLine1;

    @Column(name="ADDRESS_LINE2" , nullable=true)
    private String addressLine2;

    @Column(name="ADDRESS_LINE3" , nullable=true)
    private String addressLine3;

    @Column(name="CITY", length=50, nullable=true)
    private String city;

    @Column(name="COUNTRY", length=25, nullable=true)
    private String country;


// the setters and getter are removed as they are generated using eclipse code snippet.

The Dao and its Implementation are using the java reflection API.

public interface Dao<T, ID> extends Serializable {

    public T save(T entity);

    public T update(T entity);
}
```

The Other Methods have been removed and are working fine the save is working fine but only problem with the update.

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<T, ID extends Serializable> implements Dao<T, ID>  {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final Class<T> persistentClass;
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;// = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao(){
        this.persistentClass =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    protected Session getSession(){
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public Class<T> getPersistentClass(){
        return persistentClass;
    }
    @Override
    public T save(final T entity) {
        this.getSession().persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.sounds.bvs.data.dao.Dao#update(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public T update(final T entity) {
        this.getSession().update(entity);
        return entity;
    }
}

// This implementation is working for the single table insertion and updates where it doesn't involve any OneToOne relations or others.


The Client Service interface.

public interface ClientsService extends ClientsDao {

}
```

the Client service implementation.  I'm setting the clientDetails with clients in both the clients save and update operation if i don't do this the forging key is not saving in the child table. what I'm doing below is right?

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ClientsServiceImpl implements ClientsService {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    ClientsDao dao; 

@Override
    public Clients save(Clients entity) {
        entity.getClientDetails().setClients(entity);
        return this.dao.save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public Clients update(Clients entity) {
        entity.getClientDetails().setClients(entity);
        return this.dao.update(entity);
    }
}
```

The Controller Class of the Clients.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin_clients")
public class ClientController {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClientController.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private ClientsService clientsService;

@RequestMapping(value="/save_client", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveClient(@Valid @ModelAttribute Clients clients, Errors errors) {
        logger.info("Invoking saveClient and client id is " + clients.getId());
        if (errors.hasErrors()) return "add_client";
        if(clients.getId() == null) {
            this.clientsService.save(clients);
        }else {
            this.clientsService.update(clients);
        }

        return back();
    }
}
```

The back() method will redirect to client list page which is working fine.

The Client Details Maintainance Page contains the JSP code of saving and editing the client details class field values.

```
<form:form cssClass="form-horizontal" action="${addClient}" method="POST" modelAttribute="clients" >
                <form:hidden path="id" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cName" class="col-sm-2">Client Name : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:input path="clientName" id="cName" cssClass="form-control" />
                        <form:errors path="clientName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cAddress" class="col-sm-2">Client Address</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:textarea id="cAddress" cssClass="form-control" path="clientDetails.addressDetails.address.addressLine1" rows="2" cols="20"/>
                        <form:errors path="clientDetails.addressDetails.address.addressLine1"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cCity" class="col-sm-2"> City</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:input id="cCity" cssClass="form-control" path="clientDetails.addressDetails.address.city"/>
                        <form:errors path="clientDetails.addressDetails.address.city" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cCountry" class="col-sm-2"> Country</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:input id="cCountry" cssClass="form-control" path="clientDetails.addressDetails.address.country"/>
                        <form:errors path="clientDetails.addressDetails.address.country" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save" />
                        <a href="${back}" class="btn btn-default"> Back</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form:form>
```

The Output One the Save is Working fine. here is the logger output

The First time Page load fetch operation and saving operation.

```
INFO: Server startup in 35774 ms
2017-06-18 23:00:41 INFO  ClientController:29 - Invoking goToClients
Hibernate: select this_.SYSID as SYSID1_1_0_, this_.CREATED_BY as CREATED_2_1_0_, this_.CREATED_ON as CREATED_3_1_0_, this_.MODIFIED_BY as MODIFIED4_1_0_, this_.MODIFIED_ON as MODIFIED5_1_0_, this_.CLIENT_NAME as CLIENT_N6_1_0_, this_.VERSION as VERSION7_1_0_ from CLN_HDR_TB this_
2017-06-18 23:00:45 INFO  ClientController:43 - Invoking addClient
2017-06-18 23:01:05 INFO  ClientController:50 - Invoking saveClient and client id is null
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into CLN_HDR_TB (CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_ON, CLIENT_NAME, VERSION, SYSID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)


Hibernate: insert into CLN_DTL_TB (ADDRESS_LINE1, ADDRESS_LINE2, ADDRESS_LINE3, CITY, COUNTRY, OFF_MOB, OFF_PHN, PER_MOB, PER_PHN, PIN, PRY_EMAIL_ID, SEC_EMAIL_ID, CONTACT_PERSON_NAME, CONTACT_REFERENCE, CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_ON, CLN_DESC, C_ID, VERSION, SYSID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)



2017-06-18 23:01:06 INFO  ClientController:29 - Invoking goToClients
Hibernate: select this_.SYSID as SYSID1_1_0_, this_.CREATED_BY as CREATED_2_1_0_, this_.CREATED_ON as CREATED_3_1_0_, this_.MODIFIED_BY as MODIFIED4_1_0_, this_.MODIFIED_ON as MODIFIED5_1_0_, this_.CLIENT_NAME as CLIENT_N6_1_0_, this_.VERSION as VERSION7_1_0_ from CLN_HDR_TB this_
Hibernate: select clientsdet0_.SYSID as SYSID1_0_1_, clientsdet0_.ADDRESS_LINE1 as ADDRESS_2_0_1_, clientsdet0_.ADDRESS_LINE2 as ADDRESS_3_0_1_, clientsdet0_.ADDRESS_LINE3 as ADDRESS_4_0_1_, clientsdet0_.CITY as CITY5_0_1_, clientsdet0_.COUNTRY as COUNTRY6_0_1_, clientsdet0_.OFF_MOB as OFF_MOB7_0_1_, clientsdet0_.OFF_PHN as OFF_PHN8_0_1_, clientsdet0_.PER_MOB as PER_MOB9_0_1_, clientsdet0_.PER_PHN as PER_PHN10_0_1_, clientsdet0_.PIN as PIN11_0_1_, clientsdet0_.PRY_EMAIL_ID as PRY_EMA12_0_1_, clientsdet0_.SEC_EMAIL_ID as SEC_EMA13_0_1_, clientsdet0_.CONTACT_PERSON_NAME as CONTACT14_0_1_, clientsdet0_.CONTACT_REFERENCE as CONTACT15_0_1_, clientsdet0_.CREATED_BY as CREATED16_0_1_, clientsdet0_.CREATED_ON as CREATED17_0_1_, clientsdet0_.MODIFIED_BY as MODIFIE18_0_1_, clientsdet0_.MODIFIED_ON as MODIFIE19_0_1_, clientsdet0_.CLN_DESC as CLN_DES20_0_1_, clientsdet0_.C_ID as C_ID22_0_1_, clientsdet0_.VERSION as VERSION21_0_1_, clients1_.SYSID as SYSID1_1_0_, clients1_.CREATED_BY as CREATED_2_1_0_, clients1_.CREATED_ON as CREATED_3_1_0_, clients1_.MODIFIED_BY as MODIFIED4_1_0_, clients1_.MODIFIED_ON as MODIFIED5_1_0_, clients1_.CLIENT_NAME as CLIENT_N6_1_0_, clients1_.VERSION as VERSION7_1_0_ from CLN_DTL_TB clientsdet0_ left outer join CLN_HDR_TB clients1_ on clientsdet0_.C_ID=clients1_.SYSID where clientsdet0_.C_ID=?
```

The database structure and its reference. The Clients Table (The Parent)

```
SYSID ,CREATED_BY,CREATED_ON,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_ON,CLIENT_NAME    VERSION
        1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Oracle  0
```

The Child Table and its Values remaning colums are been removed

```
SYSID   ADDRESS_LINE1   CITY    COUNTRY     VERSION     C_ID
2   Oracle bangalore    Banagalore  India   0   1
```

The Update Operation on the First time the Parent table is update for the version number and all the fields are set for update.

Why all the fields are setting for the update?

the child table column values are not getting update.

```
  2017-06-18 23:07:46 INFO  ClientController:50 - Invoking saveClient and client id is 1



 Hibernate: update CLN_HDR_TB set MODIFIED_BY=?, MODIFIED_ON=?, CLIENT_NAME=?, VERSION=? where SYSID=? and VERSION=?
        2017-06-18 23:07:46 INFO  ClientController:29 - Invoking goToClients
        Hibernate: select this_.SYSID as SYSID1_1_0_, this_.CREATED_BY as CREATED_2_1_0_, this_.CREATED_ON as CREATED_3_1_0_, this_.MODIFIED_BY as MODIFIED4_1_0_, this_.MODIFIED_ON as MODIFIED5_1_0_, this_.CLIENT_NAME as CLIENT_N6_1_0_, this_.VERSION as VERSION7_1_0_ from CLN_HDR_TB this_




 Hibernate: select clientsdet0_.SYSID as SYSID1_0_1_, clientsdet0_.ADDRESS_LINE1 as ADDRESS_2_0_1_, clientsdet0_.ADDRESS_LINE2 as ADDRESS_3_0_1_, clientsdet0_.ADDRESS_LINE3 as ADDRESS_4_0_1_, clientsdet0_.CITY as CITY5_0_1_, clientsdet0_.COUNTRY as COUNTRY6_0_1_, clientsdet0_.OFF_MOB as OFF_MOB7_0_1_, clientsdet0_.OFF_PHN as OFF_PHN8_0_1_, clientsdet0_.PER_MOB as PER_MOB9_0_1_, clientsdet0_.PER_PHN as PER_PHN10_0_1_, clientsdet0_.PIN as PIN11_0_1_, clientsdet0_.PRY_EMAIL_ID as PRY_EMA12_0_1_, clientsdet0_.SEC_EMAIL_ID as SEC_EMA13_0_1_, clientsdet0_.CONTACT_PERSON_NAME as CONTACT14_0_1_, clientsdet0_.CONTACT_REFERENCE as CONTACT15_0_1_, clientsdet0_.CREATED_BY as CREATED16_0_1_, clientsdet0_.CREATED_ON as CREATED17_0_1_, clientsdet0_.MODIFIED_BY as MODIFIE18_0_1_, clientsdet0_.MODIFIED_ON as MODIFIE19_0_1_, clientsdet0_.CLN_DESC as CLN_DES20_0_1_, clientsdet0_.C_ID as C_ID22_0_1_, clientsdet0_.VERSION as VERSION21_0_1_, clients1_.SYSID as SYSID1_1_0_, clients1_.CREATED_BY as CREATED_2_1_0_, clients1_.CREATED_ON as CREATED_3_1_0_, clients1_.MODIFIED_BY as MODIFIED4_1_0_, clients1_.MODIFIED_ON as MODIFIED5_1_0_, clients1_.CLIENT_NAME as CLIENT_N6_1_0_, clients1_.VERSION as VERSION7_1_0_ from CLN_DTL_TB clientsdet0_ left outer join CLN_HDR_TB clients1_ on clientsdet0_.C_ID=clients1_.SYSID where clientsdet0_.C_ID=?
```

When i do the second time i get this below error. and its trace is below. and y is always the header table is getting updated not the child table.

```
  4





  2017-06-18 23:08:39 INFO  ClientController:50 - Invoking saveClient and client id is 1
        Hibernate: update CLN_HDR_TB set MODIFIED_BY=?, MODIFIED_ON=?, CLIENT_NAME=?, VERSION=? where SYSID=? and VERSION=?
        2017-06-18 23:08:39 ERROR SessionImpl:3166 - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1]
        2017-06-18 23:08:39 INFO  AbstractBatchImpl:193 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
        Jun 18, 2017 11:08:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
        SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/EnterpriseSpringApplication] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1] with root cause
        org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

Comment: If this code works fine, then it is off topic on Stack Overflow, but would be very good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No there is an Exception still please look till end.

Comment: Please take a few minutes then to format your question so that this is clear.  In particular, do not indent anything that is not code.

Comment: Well now the formatting makes more sense, but your question really needs a re-write. You keep saying several times "this is my question", so which one is it?

Comment: when i do a update operation on clients the child table address city and country colums are not getting updated instead the parent table version is getting updated and throwing the above error.

Comment: I found a way to update the child table by keeping the id and version number of the parent and child talbe is spring hidden element tag. is this the way to store the id and version numbers please look over the above contoller and JSP newly added code                         
                                 <form:hidden path="id" />
    <form:hidden path="version" />
    <form:hidden path="clientDetails.id" />
    <form:hidden path="clientDetails.version" />

Comment: Found a better solution or i missed the basic step to use session attribute annotation will resolve the issue

Comment: I'm having issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73091178/data-inconsistancy-parent-table-is-not-updated-while-child-table-is-updated